# Issue during import, MLRunNotFoundError

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, mlops, mlrun

I installed python package MLRun correctly, but I got in jupyter this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlrun/errors.py in raise_for_status(response, message)
     75     try:
---> 76         response.raise_for_status()
     77     except requests.HTTPError as exc:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py in raise_for_status(self)
    942         if http_error_msg:
--> 943             raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
    944 

HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://mlrun-api.default-tenant.app.iguazio.prod//api/v1/client-spec
...
/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlrun/errors.py in raise_for_status(response, message)
     80             error_message = f"{str(exc)}: {message}"
     81         try:
---> 82             raise STATUS_ERRORS[response.status_code](
     83                 error_message, response=response
     84             ) from exc

MLRunNotFoundError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://mlrun-api.default-tenant.app.iguazio.prod//api/v1/client-spec: details: Not Found
```

based on this source code in python:

```
%pip install mlrun scikit-learn~=1.0
import mlrun
...
```

Do you see issues?

BTW: I installed relevant MLRun version (the same as on server side). I modified file `mlrun.env` and added values for these variables `MLRUN_DBPATH`, `V3IO_USERNAME`, `V3IO_ACCESS_KEY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue**

I got it, the problem is in invalid url, see error message `Not Found for url: https://mlrun-api.default-tenant.app.iguazio.prod//api/v1/client-spec`.

You can see double **`//`** and it is the issue, variable MLRUN_DB contains this url 'https://mlrun-api.default-tenant.app.iguazio.prod/'.

**Solution**

You have to remove end **`/`** in MLRUN_DB and final value will be **`MLRUN_DB=https://mlrun-api.default-tenant.app.iguazio.prod`**

Now it works.